# ValueError: continuous format is not supported

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, classification, valueerror

I have written a simple function where I am using the [average_precision_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html) from `scikit-learn` to compute average precision.

My Code:

```py
def compute_average_precision(predictions, gold):
    gold_predictions = np.zeros(predictions.size, dtype=np.int)
    for idx in range(gold):
        gold_predictions[idx] = 1
    return average_precision_score(predictions, gold_predictions)
```

When the function is executed, it produces the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 91, in <module>
    total_avg_precision += compute_average_precision(np.asarray(probs), len(gold_candidates))
  File "test.py", line 29, in compute_average_precision
    return average_precision_score(predictions, gold_predictions)
  File "/if5/wua4nw/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py", line 184, in average_precision_score
    average, sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/if5/wua4nw/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/base.py", line 81, in _average_binary_score
    raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
ValueError: continuous format is not supported
```

If I print the two numpy arrays `predictions` and `gold_predictions`, say for one example, it looks alright. [One example is provided below.]

```
[ 0.40865014  0.26047812  0.07588802  0.26604077  0.10586583  0.17118802
  0.26797949  0.34618672  0.33659923  0.22075308  0.42288553  0.24908153
  0.26506338  0.28224747  0.32942101  0.19986877  0.39831917  0.23635269
  0.34715138  0.39831917  0.23635269  0.35822859  0.12110706]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

What I am doing wrong here? What is the meaning of the error?

Comment: What does this `predictions` represent? Are they outputs of the predict() method of some estimator or do they represent the probability of getting the positive class, or maybe output of `predict_proba()`? Anyways, `y_true` or your `gold_predictions` need to be the first argument and `predictions` second.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just taking a look at the [`sklearn` docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html)

> Parameters:
>
> y_true : array, shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_classes] True
>   binary labels in binary label indicators.
>
> y_score : array, shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_classes] Target
>   scores, can either be probability estimates of the positive class,
>   confidence values, or non-thresholded measure of decisions (as
>   returned by “decision_function” on some classifiers).

So your first argument has to be an array of binary labels, but you are passing some sort of float array as the first argument. So I believe you need to reverse the order of the arguments you are passing.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the metrics in scikit-learn work on only specific types of target data. Scikit-learn employs a utility function [`sklearn.utils.multiclass.type_of_target`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.multiclass.type_of_target.html), to check the type of the target data. The following are the possible types:

- continuous, e.g. `np.random.rand(100)`
- continuous-multioutput, e.g. `np.random.rand(100,2)`
- binary, e.g. `np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100)`
- multiclass, e.g. `np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], size=100)`
- multiclass-multioutput, e.g. `np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], size=(100,2))`
- multilabel-indicator, e.g. `np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(100,2))`
- unknown, e.g. `np.random.rand(100).astype(object)`

The first argument passed to any metric function determines the type of target data. So in the example in the OP, the internal type checking is done on `predictions` variable, such as the following.

```py
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import type_of_target
type_of_target(predictions)   # 'continuous'
```

---

The most common way this error occurs is when one passes an unsupported target type (perhaps ordered args incorrectly as in the OP) when using a metric that assesses performance on a classification task given **scores**. The following table summarizes all supported types of such metrics.

|  | continuous | continuous- multioutput | binary | multiclass | multiclass- multioutput | multilabel- indicator | unknown |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [average precision score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html) |  |  | ✔ |  |  | ✔ |  |
| [coverage error](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.coverage_error.html) |  |  |  |  |  | ✔ |  |
| [dcg score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.dcg_score.html) |  | ✔ |  |  | ✔ | ✔ |  |
| [det curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.det_curve.html) |  |  | ✔ |  |  |  |  |
| [label ranking average precision score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.label_ranking_average_precision_score.html) |  |  |  |  |  | ✔ |  |
| [label ranking loss](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.label_ranking_loss.html) |  |  |  |  |  | ✔ |  |
| [ndcg score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ndcg_score.html) |  | ✔ |  |  | ✔ | ✔ |  |
| [precision recall curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html) |  |  | ✔ |  |  |  |  |
| [roc auc score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) |  |  | ✔ | ✔ `multi_class=` must be passed |  | ✔ |  |
| [roc curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html) |  |  | ✔ |  |  |  |  |
| [top-k accuracy score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.top_k_accuracy_score.html) |  |  | ✔ | ✔ |  |  |  |

---

There are also metrics that assess performance on classification task given **class prediction**. They generally work on binary, multiclass or multilabel-indicator target types. If a "wrong" target type is fed to it, a related `ValueError: Unknown label type` or `ValueError: y should be a 1d array` errors are thrown. The following summarizes which metric admits which target type.

- [`accuracy_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html), [`classification_report`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html), [`f1_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html), [`fbeta_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.fbeta_score.html), [`hamming_loss`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.hamming_loss.html), [`jaccard_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html), [`log_loss`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html), [`multilabel_confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.multilabel_confusion_matrix.html), [`precision_recall_fscore_support`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html), [`precision_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html), [`recall_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html), [`zero_one_loss`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.zero_one_loss.html) work on binary, multiclass or multilabel-indicator target types
- [`balanced_accuracy_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score.html), [`cohen_kappa_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score.html), [`confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html), [`hinge_loss`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.hinge_loss.html), [`matthews_corrcoef`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.matthews_corrcoef.html) only work on binary or multiclass
- [`brier_score_loss`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.brier_score_loss.html) only works on binary

Yet another adjacent error is `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of target types`. This occurs when the type of predictions don't match the type of true values, i.e. it happens when `type_of_target(y_true) != type_of_target(y_pred)`. Make sure they are the same.

---

Yet another way this error occurs is if you create a custom scorer using `sklearn.metrics.make_scorer` with `needs_threshold=True`. In that case, only binary or multilabel-indicator target types are accepted, even if the underlying metric passed to the scorer works on another target type. For example, `sklearn.metrics.top_k_accuracy_score` works on multiclass target types but if it is made into a scorer via `metrics.make_scorer` that needs a threshold, then it wouldn't work anymore.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model, metrics, datasets

X, y = datasets.make_classification(n_informative=3, n_classes=3)   # multiclass
lr = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)

metrics.top_k_accuracy_score(y, lr.decision_function(X))   # <--- OK

scorer = metrics.make_scorer(metrics.top_k_accuracy_score, needs_threshold=True)
scorer(lr, X, y)                                           # <--- ValueError: multiclass format is not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all previous two detailed answers. But the solution seems so easy:
you just need to exchange the positions of two inputs...

That is, `average_precision_score(gold_predictions, predictions)`

[image]